# How do I fix my table when stratifying by two variables using table1 R package?

Tags: r, html-table, summary

I am trying to use the table1 package in R to create a table of summary statistics while stratifying by year (2017-2022) and pandemic super-categories (pre-pandemic and during the Covid-19 pandemic). I am able to create a table using Method 1, however, this method required me to remove the "Overall" column (which was actually six columns, one for each year) and I would like to be able to include it (see imgur link [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO97H.png)).

#Method 1

```
`table1(~ `Disease Type 2` + `Citation Type 2` + `Reference Type 2` + `Guideline Type 2` + `Subject Type 2` + `Becker Model Domain 2` | 
      Pandemic*Year, 
      data = Final_Data2, 
      topclass="Rtable1-shade",
      overall = FALSE)`
```

To try to fix this problem, I adopted the code in Method 2 from Example #2 of this CRAN Documentation (and, in fairness, I don't entirely understand the rationale behind all of the code):

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html

#Method 2

```
 #Cleaning Labels

label(Final_Data2$`Disease Type 2`) <- "Disease Type"
label(Final_Data2$`Citation Type 2`) <- "Citation Type"
label(Final_Data2$`Reference Type 2`) <- "Reference Type"
label(Final_Data2$`Guideline Type 2`) <- "Guideline Type"
label(Final_Data2$`Subject Type 2`) <- "Subject Type"
label(Final_Data2$`Becker Model Domain 2`) <- "Becker Model Domain"

#Creating Covid Pandemic Timeline

Final_Data2$Pandemic <- Final_Data2$Year

as_factor(Final_Data2$Pandemic)

Final_Data2$Pandemic <- fct_collapse(Final_Data2$Pandemic,
    "Pre-Pandemic" = c("2017", "2018", "2019"),
    "Covid-19 Pandemic" = c("2020", "2021", "2022")
    )

  #Creating stratification by Covid-19 pandemic period for table
Final_Data2$Year <- factor(Final_Data2$Year, levels=c("2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022"))

strata <- c(split(Final_Data2, Final_Data2$Year),
            list(Overall=Final_Data2))

labels <- list(
  variables=list(disease=render.varlabel(Final_Data2$`Disease Type 2`),
                 citation=render.varlabel(Final_Data2$`Citation Type 2`),
                 reference=render.varlabel(Final_Data2$`Guideline Type 2`),
                 subject=render.varlabel(Final_Data2$`Subject Type 2`),
                 becker=render.varlabel(Final_Data2$`Becker Model Domain 2`)),
  groups=list("Pre-Pandemic", "Covid-19 Pandemic", ""))

table1(strata, labels, groupspan=c(3, 3, 1))
```

Now I have run into another problem. When I go to make my table 1 the category levels have been removed (only the variable headings remain) and there are NAs instead of counts in the table itself (see the imgur link [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeeCf.png)).

How can I fix either Method 1 to only show one "Overall" column that counts all of my observations or Method 2 to show my results?

Comment: can you share you data? have you looked into other tabling packages like `gtsummary` or `summarytools`

Comment: Unfortunately the data is proprietary so it can't be shared. The gtsummary documentation isn't helpful and I'm having a difficult time trying to work my way through it. I'm still learning how to speak "coder" so I need more a more detailed walkthrough than the documentation that either table1 and gtsummary provide.

Comment: ok in that case you need to share images of the tables you want and the expected output so others can help. additionally it would be helpful to 'mock' up some data that shows your exact issue to make it reproducible

Comment: There are pictures imbedded in linked numbers in my post. Are those not enough to help? Basically, I want to reduce the number of "Overall" categories from 6 to 1 (one summarizing all counts rather than one column per each of the 6 years) with the code from Method 1 as seen in Image 1. Or, alternatively, I need to  figure out how to populate the table with counts using Method 2 as seen in Image 2.